# Chisel: getting signal name in final Verilog

Tags: chisel

I'd like to automate as much as possible the instantiation of an ILA directly from the Chisel code. This means instantiating a module that looks like this:

```
i_ila my_ila(
.clk(clock),
.probe0(a_signal_to_monitor),
.probe1(another_signal_to_monitor),
// and so on
);
```

I'm planning to store the signals that I want to monitor in a list of `UInt` so that at the end of module elaboration I can generate the instantiation code above, which I will copy/paste in the final Verilog code (or write a Python script that does that automatically).

First, is there a better way of doing this, perhaps at the level of FIRRTL?

Even if I go with this semi-manual approach, I need to know what would be the name of the signals in the final Verilog, which is not necessarily the name of the `UInt` vals in the code (and which, besides, I don't know how to get automatically without having to retype the name of the variable as a string somewhere). How can I get them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to provide a more complete example, but I wanted to make sure to at least write something up. This also needs to be fleshed out as a proper example/tutorial on the website.

FIRRTL has robust support for tracking names of signals across built-in and custom transformations. This is a case where the infrastructure is all there, but it's very much a power user API. In short, you can create FIRRTL [Annotations](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/firrtl/1.4.0/firrtl/annotations/Annotation.html) that will track [Targets](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/firrtl/1.4.0/firrtl/annotations/Target.html). You can then emit custom metadata files or use the normal FIRRTL annotation file (try the CLI option `-foaf` / `--output-annotation-file`).

An example FIRRTL Annotation that has will emit a custom metadata file at the end of compilation:

```scala
// Example FIRRTL annotation with Custom serialization
// FIRRTL will track the name of this signal through compilation
case class MyMetadataAnno(target: ReferenceTarget)
    extends SingleTargetAnnotation[ReferenceTarget]
    with CustomFileEmission {
  def duplicate(n: ReferenceTarget) = this.copy(n)

  // API for serializing a custom metadata file
  // Note that multiple of this annotation will collide which is an error, not handled in this example
  protected def baseFileName(annotations: AnnotationSeq): String = "my_metadata"
  protected def suffix: Option[String] = Some(".txt")
  def getBytes: Iterable[Byte] =
    s"Annotated signal: ${target.serialize}".getBytes
}
```

The `case class` declaration and `duplicate` method are enough to track a single signal through compilation. The `CustomFileEmission` and related `baseFileName`, `suffix`, and `getBytes` methods define how to serialize my custom metadata file. As mentioned in the comment, as implemented in this example we can only have 1 instance of this `MyMetadataAnno` or they will try to write the same file which is an error. This can be handled by customizing the filename based on the `Target`, or writing a FIRRTL transform to aggregate multiple of this annotation into a single annotation.

We then need a way to create this annotation in Chisel:

```scala
  def markSignal[T <: Data](x: T): T = {
    annotate(new ChiselAnnotation {
      // We can't call .toTarget until end of Chisel elaboration
      // .toFirrtl is called by Chisel at the end of elaboration
      def toFirrtl = MyMetadataAnno(x.toTarget)
    })
    x
  }
```

Now all we need to do is use this simple API in our Chisel

```scala
// Simple example with a marked signal
class Foo extends MultiIOModule {
  val in = IO(Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(8.W))))
  val out = IO(Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))

  markSignal(out.valid)

  out <> in
}
```

This will result in writing the file `my_metadata.txt` to the target directory with the contents:

```
Annotated signal: ~Foo|Foo>out_valid
```

Note that this is special FIRRTL target syntax saying that `out_valid` is the annotated signal that lives in module `Foo`.

Complete code in an executable example:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/moEiIqZPTRCR5mLQNrV3zA