# Chisel and Timing Constraints files

Tags: chisel

Apologies in advance for the perhaps stupid question. Is it possible to integrate into the CHISEL flow a Scala script that generate timing constraint specifications (SDC) for a given design? e.g. press a button and you get your CHISEL design converted to Verilog along with an SDC file, ready for synthesis.

I currently have such a toolflow in place for VHDL (using python to generate the constraints files). But in VHDL the naming conventions are quite clear, not so sure about the CHISEL backend (also I couldn't find any reference on the web doing this)

Is it possible, or this is just not how CHISEL was intended to be used ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chisel has an annotation system to support tracking and linking against signals in the emitted Verilog. I've described this system in a previous question here on StackOverflow: [Chisel: getting signal name in final Verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64349930/chisel-getting-signal-name-in-final-verilog)

There is existing work to leverage this support and build physical design flows, see [Hammer](https://github.com/ucb-bar/hammer) which is used by [Chipyard](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chipyard).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers, Jack! Highly appreciated!